# About reading file in c

Tags: c

So i just got an assigment from my prof to make a program that would read or write a file . And i got some problem when reading an empty file , whenever i read an empty file it would input a space character and 0.0 . So is there any way to

Handle this ?

Here is my read code

```
void read()
{
    n = 0  ;     
    FILE *f ;

    f = fopen("namafile.txt","r");
    if (f)
    {
        while (!feof(f))
        {
            fscanf(f,"%[^|]|%[^#]#%f\n", mhs[n].nim, mhs[n].nama, &mhs[n].x) ;
            n++ ;
        }     
    }
    else
    {
        printf("file not found\n");
    }
    fclose(f) ;

}
```

Comment: Is it [tag:c++] or [tag:c], it's not the same language.

Comment: Why is your code bad?

Comment: sorry if its bad :D , i just a begginer hehe.. can you give me some suggestion how to write a good code ??

Comment: its kinda mix since my prof teach me C + C++ library and  using c++ compiler

Comment: Get a new prof. C and C++ are different languages. If you compile with a C++ compiler it is C++ and you should use C++ features.

Comment: trust me i want that but i cant .

Comment: they use visual c++ to compile c code and too many rule  and some of em even said C++ isnt a language .

Comment: On a side-note: you should [never use `while(!feof(file))`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Answer (score 1):

The `EOF` marker will be set after `fscanf()` fails, so you need a failing `fscanf()` in order for the loop to end. Also, you have to check if `fscanf()` succeeded for which you check it's return value, that said all you need is to change this

```
while (!feof(f))
```

to

```
while (fscanf(f,"%[^|]|%[^#]#%f\n", mhs[n].nim, mhs[n].nama, &mhs[n].x) == 3)
```

NOTE: Don't use identifiers like `f`, that's a bad habit that you can porbably justify if your IDE has no autocomplete feature, but it's hardly the case, you can name your identifier `file` instead to make it clear what it is.